# Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have `UIButton` within `UIableViewCell` when i try to outlet the property from the UIButton the fallowing error is shown , what should i be doing??

> error: Illegal Configuration: The button outlet from the
>   ViewController to the UIButton is invalid. Outlets cannot be connected
>   to repeating content.

Comment: I guess you have created tableviewcell inside tableview so you need to implement & interface tableviewcell name Like view controller classes.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to outlet a `UIButton` inside a `UITableViewCell` into the actual controller.

Comment: hi..was your problem solved